Saints who recommended perpetual continence to married couples?
St. Catherine of Siena recommended perpetual continence ("angelic continence" or spiritual marriage) to at least two married couples:

Giovanni Trenta of Lucca & Monna Tora of Lucca in 1376 (Letters vol. 2, pp. 51-4)
Ristoro Canigiani & Alessandra (Sandra) Quaratesi in 1378 (Letters vol. 3, pp. 209-12)

Did other saints recommend perpetual continence to married couples?
cf. "Do married couples need to live sexually?"
